# Image glitch in Image.network or NetworkImage

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hi I'm loading my profile pics from my server in Image.network and showing it in a pageview to show next pictures. But when my image load from the internet it become a glitch as shown in the picture.

[image: Glitch Image from emulator]

**But when i open the same link in google chrome there is no glitch in my profile pic**

[image: Image from google chrome]

**This is the code is what i used to list**

```
      photos.forEach((photo) {
        profileImages.add(
          Container(
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                    APis().imageApi(
                      photo.photoName,
                    ),
                  ),
                  filterQuality: FilterQuality.low,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                      gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                        Colors.black12,
                        Colors.transparent,
                        Colors.black,
                      ], stops: [
                        0.25,
                        0.75,
                        1.0
                      ], begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter, end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
      print("profileImages :${photos.length} ${profileImages.length}");
    }
```

**And this is what i displaying in pageview**

```
PageView.builder(
  controller: pageController,
  onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
  itemCount: profileImages.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
  return profileImages[position];
})
```

So my question is do i have to change anything or do i have to put placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've handled it is by using a placeholder, so I use a Stack, i put the placeholder image underneath it and then once it loads, it just shows on top.

See the before and after:

[image: image with placeholders]
[image: image already loaded]

And the code just pretty much looks like this:

```
ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('assets/placeholder.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  width: 600.0,
                  height: 900.0
                ),
                Image.network(imgPath,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  width: 600.0,
                  height: 900.0
                )]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea. But now there is a widget which is for placeholder with network image which is way more easy to implement. https://youtu.be/pK738Pg9cxc check this link.

Comment: Yes, please use the Flutter provided one of course! When I created this approach, that widget didn't exist!

Comment: I'm using flutter dev version. and also i found that its the problem of some emulator too.. When i run in my phone it works fine